# Postgres search a char X but not XX

Tags: regex, postgresql

Hi I'm trying to find strings in a table that have '=' but not that are '==' in a postgrs table. If I use the following search

```
SELECT * FROM someTable where someColumn ~ ' R ';
```

I find all string with R. But I want to exlude this one that are RR, but if a string has 'something R other RR other' I would it have as result.

Can you geve me some tips on how to resolve this?

Tank's.

Comment: why not `like '%R%' and not like '%RR%' `?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and do something like so: `SELECT * FROM someTable where someColumn ~ ' R[^R] ';`

This should match any string `R` which is *not* followed by another `R`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regex, *word boundaries*, `\y` can be used here:

```
select * from your_table where s ~ '\yR\y';
```

See [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ESCAPE-SEQUENCES):

> `\y`    matches only at the beginning or end of a word

See an [online test](http://rextester.com/TUT33830):

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (s character varying)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (s)
VALUES
     ('R'),
    ('that are RR'),
    ('that are R')
;
select * from table1 where s ~ '\yR\y';
```

Output:

```
    s
1   R
2   that are R
```